# Gravity Forms Google Nocaptcha Recaptcha image picker wider than mobile screen

Tags: responsive-design, recaptcha, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm having an issue with Gravity forms' Google noCaptcha reCaptcha (Wordpress Plugin). The pop-up image picker (after you check the box it pops up) is going off of the screen in a mobile size window. It's the only element that does that, so I'm lead to believe that it's not an issue with my styling. Has this ever happened to anyone before? I've tried researching it but the only thing I can find is talking about the "I'm Not a Robot" box not being responsive, which is NOT my issue here. 
Here's an image of the site before the box is checked:

[image]

And here is an image of after it's checked:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can fix that with css. Have you tried this solution ? http://www.scriptscoop.com/t/6d0a4ba8dc7e/html-why-didnt-google-make-the-new-v2-recaptcha-mobile-friendly.html

Comment: Thanks! I hadn't seen that article before. If you'd like to make this an answer instead of a comment, I'll mark this question answered.

Comment: I have added it as answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix that issue with css. Kindly read this http://www.scriptscoop.com/t/6d0a4ba8dc7e/html-why-didnt-google-make-the-new-v2-recaptcha-mobile-friendly.html